# Problem with identifying a button in a flatlist in React-Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, button, flatlist

I'm using React-Native and I'm having problems with identifiyng which button was pressed inside a flatlist. I can make them all change, but I want to make them change separately.

I already put an identifier in each element called `num`, but I don't know how to identify each button. My idea is having each button with an *id* (`num`), and in the `onPress` prop identify which button was pressed and change its color.

Also, I don't know if I will have to make different CSS for each button or if I can change them from `main`.

Main:

```
const main = () => {

  const [pressedButton, setPressedButton] = useState("#1e1e1e")

  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <View style = {styles.nav}>
        <View style={styles.nav_container}>
          <Text style = {styles.title_main}>Habits</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.divider_main} />
      </View>
      <ScrollView style = {styles.body_main}>
        <FlatList
          data = {[
            {key: "Habit", desc: "30 Minutes a Day", num: 0},
            {key: "Habit", desc: "30 Minutes a Day", num: 1},
            {key: "Habit", desc: "30 Minutes a Day", num: 2},
            {key: "Habit", desc: "30 Minutes a Day", num: 3},
          ]}
          renderItem = {({item}) =>
            <View style = {styles.list_item}>
              <Text style = {styles.list_item_text}>{item.key}</Text>
              <Text style = {styles.list_item_desc}>{item.desc}</Text>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress = {() => {
                  pressedButton == "#1e1e1e" ? setPressedButton("#9747FF") : setPressedButton("#1e1e1e")
                }}>
                <View style = {[styles.check_mark, {backgroundColor: pressedButton}]}>
                  <Image source = {require("./assets/black-check.png")} style = {styles.check_mark_img}/>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>}
          style = {styles.list_main}
        />
        
      </ScrollView>
      <View style = {styles.add_habit}>
        <View style = {styles.add_habit_vert}></View>
        <View style = {styles.add_habit_hor}></View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
check_mark: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderColor: "#9747FF",
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: "#1e1e1e",
    position: "absolute",
    right: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use index in `renderItem`.

Save that index in state with `setPressedButtonIndex` and add background style if item's index is equal to `pressedButtonIndex`

```
const [pressedButtonIndex, setPressedButtonIndex] = useState(null)

renderItem = {({item, index}) =>
            <View style = {styles.list_item}>
              <Text style = {styles.list_item_text}>{item.key}</Text>
              <Text style = {styles.list_item_desc}>{item.desc}</Text>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress = {() => {
                 setPressedButtonIndex(index)
                }}>
                <View style = {[styles.check_mark, index === pressedButtonIndex ? {backgroundColor: "#1e1e1e"} : {}]}>
                  <Image source = {require("./assets/black-check.png")} style = {styles.check_mark_img}/>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>}
          style = {styles.list_main}
```